# Angular 7 animations - Transition not working

Tags: html, css, angular, animation

I looked at other questions around the same issue and none of the solutions provided worked for me.

I'm using Angular 7.2 with "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0".

I have a div which I want to fade in and fade out. So I have applied an opacity animation to it. This same div, I use `*ngIf` to add it and remove it from HTML.

The problem is, the animation styles (opacity) is getting applied correctly but it's not transitioning nicely from opacity 1 > 0 or 0 > 1.

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="divToShow.value !== 'none'" [@openClose]="openState">Dynamic Content Here</div>
```

Animation:

```
animations: [
    trigger('openClose', [
      state('true', style({
        opacity: '1'
      })),
      state('false', style({
        opacity: '0'
      })),
      transition('true => false', [
        animate('10s')
      ]),
      transition('false => true', [
        animate('10s')
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

Getter:

```
public get openState(): string {
    if (this.divToShow.value !== 'none') {
      return 'true';
    } else {
      return 'false';
    }
  }
```

`divToShow` will be 'none' when no div is to be shown. When it does need to show a div it will have the div name as a string.

Can you please advice what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
*ngIf="divToShow.value !== 'none'"
```

The above will *remove* the `<div>` when the condition is *false*, but you can't *fade* in or out if the `<div>` doesn't exist.

Angular gives you a transition state to apply animations for when elements are added or removed from the DOM.

```js
        trigger('openClose', [
            transition(':enter', [
                style({opacity: 0}),
                animate('10s', style({opacity: 1}))
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                style({opacity: 1}),
                animate('10s', style({opacity: 0}))
            ])
        ])
```

See: https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#enter-and-leave-aliases